# Проверка на существование элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript, dom

Здравствуйте.
На странице находится ссылка с `id='offers'`
При нажатии на эту ссылку, должен подгрузиться `div` с `class='ajax_block'`.

Проблема: как сделать так, чтобы при повторном нажатии эту ссылку, подгруженный ajax пропадал? (а не добавлялся еще один такой же)

Я пытался:

```
$('#offers').click(function () {
  if(document.getElementsByClassName('ajax_block')!==null){ // те такие блоки есть
    $('.offers-ajax').remove();
  }
  else{ //те таких блоков нет надо добавить
    $.ajax({
      url: 'offers.html',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.ajax_block').append(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Решил данную проблему 
$('#offers').click(function () {
   if($('.podmenu').children().length>0){
    $('.offers-ajax').remove();    
   }
   else{
    $.ajax({
      url: 'offers.html',
      success: function(data) {
       $('.podmenu').append(data);
      }
    }); 
   }
  });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($('*').is('.ajax_block')) {
//some code
}
else {
//another code
}
```

Comment: Что *, что is() очень тяжеловесные для обработки метода. Лучше просто вычитывать lenght.

Answer (score 14):

тупое решение в лоб

```
if ($('.class').length > 0) {
    // существует
} else {
    // не существует
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
if ($('.testcss').length) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}

if ($('.testcss-no').length) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testcss">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: чем твой ответ отличается от ответа @etki данного три года назад?

Comment: Тут есть сниппет ;)

Comment: @Grundy
Еще у меня нет проверки на длину. Идет проверка на существование.